# Bibtex Style error in volume field

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am new into using TeX and BibTex.

So I've made an entry in my BibTeX database and it throws an error if I use one certain BibTeX style and if the field volume is filled.

```
@Book{Riedel2007,
  title     = {Anorganische Chemie},
  publisher = {deGruyter Verlag},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Riedel, Janiak},
  volume    = {7. Auflage},
  address   = {Berlin/New York},
  note      = {S. 349},
}
```

as the error I get the following message:

```
 ...: {\em Anorganische Chemie}, \btxvolumelong
                                                  {}\ 7. Auflage,
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I don't know what I could do.

I'm using the gerplain style. Using the plain style doesn't shows me an error.

[link to the gerplain.bst](http://ctan.mackichan.com/biblio/bibtex/contrib/germbib/bst/gerplain.bst)

Comment: I see egreg has answered, but really this file looks _ancient_: I'd strongly suggest you look at newer bibliography styles (`natbib` or `biblatex` based).

Answer (score 1):

You also need `bibgerm`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Riedel2007,
  title     = {Anorganische Chemie},
  publisher = {deGruyter Verlag},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Riedel, Janiak},
  volume    = {7. Auflage},
  address   = {Berlin/New York},
  note      = {S. 349},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\begin{document}

\cite{Riedel2007}

\bibliographystyle{gerplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Note: the `filecontents*` environment is used only for making a self-contained example.

[image]